# Calling printf() in assembly causes a 'floating point exception'

Tags: c, linux, assembly, printf, nasm

I have the following code:

```
extern printf

section .data

A db 1
B db 2
C db 3
D db 4
E db 5

fmt  db "%d",10,0
fmt2 db "An overflow has occured",10,0

section .text

    global _start

_start:
    xor rax, rax
    xor rbx, rbx
    xor rdx, rdx

    xor ax, ax
    mov al, [B]
    mul ax
    jo over
    call printax
    mov bx, ax

    xor ax, ax
    mov al, [C]
    mul ax
    jo over
    call printax

    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [C]
    mul cx
    jo over
    call printax

    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [E]
    div cx
    jo over
    call printax
    xor dx, dx

    xor al, al
    mov rdi, fmt
    call printf
    jmp exit

over:
    mov rdi, fmt2
    xor al, al
    call printf

exit:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

printbx:
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov si, bx
    mov cl, al
    xor al, al
    mov rdi, fmt
    call printf
    mov al, cl
    xor si, si
    ret

printax:
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov si, ax
    xor al, al
    mov rdi, fmt
    call printf
    mov ax, si
    xor si, si
    ret
```

I compile it with `nasm -f elf64 1.asm` and link it using `ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 1.o -o 1 -lc`. When I execute the binary, I get

```
$ ./1
4
9
0
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

`printf()` doesn't always fail when I call it in assembly code.

---

Removing `printf()` calls from `printax` and `printbx` gives me

```
$ ./1
0
```

---

Update: The exception also disappears if I remove the `div cx` line. Then I get the following output:

```
$./1
4
9
0
0
0
```

But it doesn't disappear even if I add

```
mov cx, 1
mov ax, 1
```

before `div cx`.

Comment: the only line here that can cause FPE is `div bx`

Comment: Wow. You have changed like everything in the question code. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: So when you ran it under your debugger (hint hint), which instruction triggered the exception, and what were the register values?  That should help you figure out what is happening.

Comment: A hint, though: read again about what the one-operand `div` instruction does.

Comment: Sorry for including a huge amount of text. The first example was kinda messy, so I decided to add the original code. I'll try to add a minimal reproducible example soon

Comment: When using a debugger, execution stops after (or in the process) of executing ```printf()```

Comment: Another hint: the `rsi` register is not required to be preserved by a function.  So your plan of saving the contents of `ax` in `si` across the call to `printf` doesn't work.

Comment: There is a problem in the naming of exceptions: In Linux for x86 CPUs the "Floating Point Exception" typically does describe a problem with floating points but it describes a division by zero in an integer-by-integer division!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the [x86-64 ABI calling conventions](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf).  Specifically, on page 15:

> Registers %rbp, %rbx and
>   %r12 through %r15 “belong” to the calling function and the called function is
>   required to preserve their values. In other words, a called function must preserve
>   these registers’ values for its caller. Remaining registers “belong” to the called
>   function.  If a calling function wants to preserve such a register value across a
>   function call, it must save the value in its local stack frame.

So when you call `printf`, you must assume that all registers except `rbp, rbx, r12..r15` are clobbered.  This has two effects for your program:

- You attempt to save `ax` around the call to `printf` by stashing its value in the `si` register and then putting it back later, but this doesn't help because `si` can be clobbered.
- Your `div cx` instruction divides the contents of `dx:ax` by `cx`, but `dx` might also have been clobbered.

The latter is the specific cause of the SIGFPE (which despite its name is also raised on an **integer** divide overflow), at least in my test runs. After the `printf` returns, `dx` contains some huge number, such that `dx:ax` divided by `cx` does not fit in 16 bits, which is an overflow.

(This also explains why the crash went away when you took out the `printf` call - it was no longer there to clobber your registers.)

The other lesson here is that you can't check for divide overflow on x86 by doing a `jo` afterwards; this error is primarily signaled by an exception, not by flags.  So you really have to check your operands before executing the instruction, or else arrange to handle the exception if it occurs (which is more complicated and beyond the scope of this answer).

A couple of other notes:

- Before your final call to `printf` (just before `jmp exit`), you don't load anything into `rsi`, so the value printed is garbage.
- 16-bit arithmetic is usually not to be preferred on x86-32 or x86-64 unless there is a really good reason for it.  It is no faster and bloats your code with operand size prefixes.  Better to do all your work with 32-bit arithmetic.
- Since you're using your own entry point rather than letting the C library call your `main`, this means that libc has not had the opportunity to run its own initialization code.  Therefore, it is not necessarily safe to call any libc function, particularly stdio and allocation functions.  It seems that `printf` happens to work okay in this case, and maybe it is all right for debugging, but you shouldn't plan to write your program this way for production.

Comment: Fortunately it's easy to avoid overflow: `dx:ax / cx` with DX=0 (like you normally want) overflows only if `cx=0`.  In general, you just need to check `cx!=0` and that `dx < cx`.  Same applies at any operand-size, using the appropriate registers for high-half and divisor.  Signed division (`idiv`) has more corner cases, including `INT_MIN / -1`, and I guess you'd need to some absolute-value stuff to check `|high_dividend| < |divisor|` for the general case of not just sign-extending [E/R]AX into [E/R]DX with `cdq` or whatever.